# Picture does not display and ScrollView does not scroll in Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Tried to do a mobile app. But the picture does not display on the phone when the program is ran on the phone. And scrollview does not scroll. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

[This is the output that I want. The picture part is the yellow box with text, the one with the id "header". Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRSYm.png)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_car_matcher"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="ph.com.steamrise.goodrides.CarMatcherActivity"
android:background="@drawable/carmatcher">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/header"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#80ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:text="1. What's your ideal vacation?"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"/>
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Climbing the rocky mountains"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Road trip at the city with family"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton12"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Enjoying the view on top of the mountain with friends"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton13"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Explore random places alone or with my partner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton14"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#80FFFFFF">
            <TextView
                android:text="2. How would you describe your style?"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"/>
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Sporty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton15"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Casual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton16"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Elegant"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton17"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Free-spirited"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton18"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#80FFFFFF">
            <TextView
                android:text="2. How are you with money?"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"/>
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="Really Careful- I prefer cheap stuff as long is it is usable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton19"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="I'm saving every penny and cutting corners where I can. Wait.. are you going to throw that empty can out? "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton20"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="I’m more of a “spend now, regret later” person. What’s the point of having money if you’re not going to spend it? "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton21"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="d) I’m a little risky with my money. I love playing stock market- and don’t worry, those pumpkin stocks will go up any time now"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton22"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first LinearLayout (that must be the ONLY child of the ScrollView) must be wrap_content in height, so it can be bigger than the scroll

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

And your header ImageView use android:src="@drawable/header" instead of app:srcCompat="@drawable/header"